# How to multiply a value in a filtered row (based on a given value) by another value in the same row

Tags: r, dataframe, row, multiplication

I need to multiply each value in column "Revenue" by value from each row in column "Imps" divided by 1000 but only for ID 2324. Then new value should replace the original value (Revenue). When ID is different, value in column "Revenue" should remain unchanged.

```
    ID Revenue Imps
1 8754  124.58 5429
2 8754   23.24 2393
3 8754  490.37 8845
4 2324   13.44 8934
5 2324   88.93 2345
6 1293   92.61 4985
7 1293   18.44 4592
```

I would like to added that table above is only part of the bigger table which is resizes the number of rows each day.

Many thanks for your help in advance!

This is what I tried:

```
Revenue <- ifelse(ID == "2324", Revenue %*% Imps / 1000, Revenue)
```

But I suppose it multiplied by the sum of the values ​​in the column "Imps" because final values are much bigger than expected.

Data sample:

```
structure(list(ID = c(8754, 8754, 8754, 2324, 2324, 1293, 1293
), Revenue = c(124.58, 23.24, 490.37, 13.44, 88.93, 92.61, 18.44
), Imps = c(5429, 2393, 8845, 8934, 2345, 4985, 4592)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: Assuming your dataframe is called "df", does `df$Revenue <- ifelse(df$ID == "2324", df$Revenue * (df$Imps / 1000), df$Revenue)` give you your desired outcome?

Comment: @jared_mamrot That`s correct, put it as an answer so the OP can upvote and accept it

Answer (score 0):

Does this solve your problem?

```r
df <- structure(list(ID = c(8754, 8754, 8754, 2324, 2324, 1293, 1293
), Revenue = c(124.58, 23.24, 490.37, 13.44, 88.93, 92.61, 18.44
), Imps = c(5429, 2393, 8845, 8934, 2345, 4985, 4592)),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))

df
#>     ID Revenue Imps
#> 1 8754  124.58 5429
#> 2 8754   23.24 2393
#> 3 8754  490.37 8845
#> 4 2324   13.44 8934
#> 5 2324   88.93 2345
#> 6 1293   92.61 4985
#> 7 1293   18.44 4592

df$Revenue <- ifelse(df$ID == "2324", df$Revenue * (df$Imps / 1000), df$Revenue)

df
#>     ID  Revenue Imps
#> 1 8754 124.5800 5429
#> 2 8754  23.2400 2393
#> 3 8754 490.3700 8845
#> 4 2324 120.0730 8934
#> 5 2324 208.5409 2345
#> 6 1293  92.6100 4985
#> 7 1293  18.4400 4592
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>